# Display content from database on HTML page via Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to post some content from a database on an html page. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is but my guess would be something that resembles the code below. Please let me know if there is a better way.

HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'tablepageload.php',
        data : 'test',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#echobox').html(data);
        }
     });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $sendtable = "SELECT `timein` FROM `timestamp` WHERE id='" . $latestrow . "' LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sendtable);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo $row['timein'];
};
```

Comment: This is a 5th grader question but any ways the flow would be to "Send the data to the server(PHP) via Ajax, PHP gets the required Data via MySQL query and process it further(If Required) and send the response back."

It is simple enough but you have to explore more.

Comment: you need to echo $row[0]['timein']

Comment: @Osama So how does my code fail to accomplish that? Your response wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Did you try to print_r($_POST)? What do you get when you do that because i believe you are not even getting anything at server side.

Comment: Is the personal attack on his question necessary?  Just answer it or don't

Comment: Maybe go to the Code Review side of SO? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The connection between the html file and the php file is the problem. I can successfully get the data from the database and echo it in the php file when I just view the php file in the browser. However, when I view the html file it won't display. I'm hoping there will be other 5th graders out there like me who will be relieved to find this post.

Comment: mininn9 check the edit to my answer on how to send data over to your php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workflow seems fine to me.

In essence, as already mentioned the work flow for what you're trying to achieve is:

- Make request (your initial ajax call)
- Process the request send response (your php script)
- Handle the reponse (your 'success' callback)

Looking at your code i have some pointers.

Considering using the jquery .load() function. 
If your ajax call is to do nothing more than populate a div you may aswell use this.

In terms of your sql query, i would recommend looking at:

- Prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- And if you want your latest row, order by 'id' DESC LIMIT 1.

Hope this proves helpful

EDIT: Also noticed a problem with your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : 'tablepageload.php',
    //data : 'test',
    //$_POST['test'] = "some_value",
    //$_POST['another'] = "test"
    data : {test:'some_value', another:'test'}, 
    success: function(data) {
             $('#echobox').html(data);
             }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Goon3r.